# Android - How do I properly fit bitmaps on a game?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, surfaceview

I'm developing a PacMan clone on Android, I'm currently using Netbeans IDE, on Android API 17. I have a Huawei Y330 cellphone (The device I'm developing it for), its resolution is `480x800`. I made the map so it fits almost exactly (width-wise) it's a `380x420` image. When I run the game the map is drawn a bit off screen

[image: Screenshot]

I tried resizing the **SurfaceView** but the character just disappears on the right edge of the map, which I guess it means it attempted to draw off the view. How can I display the images properly? I resized the sprites so I wouldn't have to scale them later. I'm guessing the problem is not the scale of the bitmap, but the displaying of the view itself.

```
public class Map 
{
    private final Bitmap mapImage;

    public Map(Bitmap mapImage)
    {        
        this.mapImage = mapImage;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mapImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

This is where I draw the image.

```
public MainGamePanel(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mainGame = new Game("Player", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.stepff), 
                        null, 
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map));
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);       
    setFocusable(true);
}
```

This is where I get the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the SurfaceView's Surface with the [`setFixedSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setFixedSize(int,%20int)) call. For software rendering this is generally a good idea anyway, as it prevents performance from declining severely on devices with large numbers of pixels.  The size of the Surface, and the size at which it's presented, are independent -- the Surface will be scaled appropriately if it doesn't match the View.  (Video of GLES-based demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpRaD-ij2xc).)

The trick is to get the aspect ratio right, which you can do by adjusting the size of the Surface itself (as in the demo), or by putting borders around your View.  One way to add the borders is to use a custom FrameLayout.  Grafika's [AspectFrameLayout](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/AspectFrameLayout.java) class demonstrates how to do this with a SurfaceView; see the ["Play video (SurfaceView)"](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieSurfaceActivity.java) activity for an example.